# Django REST RetrieveUpdateAPIView problem

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using generic `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` for my `API` and I want to users can retrieve and update their profile and user informations (profile) . but when I'm testing the `API` just can retrieve and update profile i can't retrieve the user .

serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user': {'read_only': True},
            'id': {'read_only': True},
        }


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

views:

```
class ProfileRetrieveUpdateView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return UserSerializer and ProfileSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = request.user
            profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
            return user and profile
        return Response(
           status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        )
```

and this is the endpoint:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you use the `and` operator. It doesn't mean what you think it means. `and` is used to check if several values are all truthy. If not, it returns false, if they are it returns the final value.
e.g.

```
>>> x = "hello" and "world"     # x == world
>>> y = False and "hello"       # y == False
```

In `get_serializer_class` both `UserSerializer` and `ProfileSerializer` are truthy. So you are just returning `ProfileSerializer`. You can return different serializers depending on different conditions, but you can not return one serializer.

In your `get` method, there is the same problem, but also a more serious problem. You can't return a `User` or `Profile` instance here. You have to return an `HttpResponse` or some subclass of it. I imagine that `if` clause is never actually being run (i.e you are not authenticated. You would get an error otherwise).

#### The solution

- If you are wanting to return user information, along with information about the profile, that should be done with a single serializer.
- It's difficult to be sure without seeing your models, but I think the `ProfileSerializer` will automatically include User information (it will be just the `user_id`). If you want more about the user, then use a nested serializer.
- I also suspect you're not logged in as a user, otherwise you would be getting other errors.
- You also shouldn't be returning a 500 error in the case of a user not being authenticated. The appropriate response code in this case would be a 401.

Comment: i want to use both serializers in the same condition and in the get method want to return both user and profile. in that situation what should i do??

Comment: @hossein-shahsavan I've updated my answer, however: With just the profile serializer, you should automatically get the user_id returned with the rest of the profile information.

Comment: ok thanks for your help .i know i didn't log in it's just test i will add permission classes .

Comment: i used nested serializer insted of using two serializer. in def get queryset() how can i get two query set i mean getting user and getting profile of that user???